# How to show that the Condition is Diophantine

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, computer-science, diophantine-equations, computability

I'm reading Matiyasevich book Hilbert's Tenth Problem, and I've got a doubt on Chapter 6, Section 6.4:

When he defines the relation: For $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

$explog(a,b)\Leftrightarrow \exists x \in \mathbb{N}  \left[x > b+1 \  \wedge \ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^{xb}  \leq a+1 < 4\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^{xb} \right]. $

He claims that it is Diophantine. But how it can be Diophantine since $\left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^{xb} $ is not an integer? Any hint would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: 
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{xb} \leq a+1 \iff \frac{(x+1)^{xb}}{x^{xb}} \leq a+1
\iff (x+1)^{xb}\leq x^{xb}(a+1)
$$
So once you know that exponentiation and inequalities are Diophantine, this condition is also Diophantine.

Comment: Thank you so very much Alex. Now it does make sense

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you're satisfied with an answer, you should "accept" it by clicking the green check-mark on the left.